# How to create a dataframe by applying a function on two vectors

Tags: r

I have two different sized character vectors, say a and b, which I would like to form the row names and column names of a new dataframe (df).

If I have a function which takes 2 arguments, an element from each of these vectors, which gives the data to go into the dataframe, how can I create it?

I've tried looking at map2 but it needs the two arguments to be the same size, and I can't quite see how I could use an apply function.

Comment: `a <- letters[1:3]; b <- LETTERS[1:5]; as.data.frame(matrix(NA, length(a), length(b), dimnames = list(a, b)))`

Comment: Thanks, that creates an empty dataframe, but let's say you wanted it populated with the output of a function which takes the row name and column name as arguments, how would you do that?

Comment: `outer`, though it returns an unnamed matrix: `a <- letters[1:3]; b <- LETTERS[1:5]; mat <- outer(a, b, paste0); dimnames(mat) <- list(a, b); as.data.frame(mat)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with a function that concatenates input strings

```
#DATA
a = letters[1:5]
b = letters[7:9]

#FUNCTION
foo = function(string1, string2){
    paste(string1, string2, sep = "")
}

#Create a dataframe with input vectors and function
setNames(object = data.frame(sapply(a, 
                    function(x) sapply(b,
                       function(y) foo(x, y))),
                row.names = b),
         nm = a)
#   a  b  c  d  e
#g ag bg cg dg eg
#h ah bh ch dh eh
#i ai bi ci di ei
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(a, col1 = b) %>%
      unite(val, a, col1, sep="", remove = FALSE) %>% 
      spread(a, val)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#   col1     a     b     c     d     e
#* <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     g    ag    bg    cg    dg    eg
#2     h    ah    bh    ch    dh    eh
#3     i    ai    bi    ci    di    ei
```

#### data

```
a <- letters[1:5]
b <- letters[7:9]
```

Comment: A bit late, but thanks so much for this. The crossing function is a new one to me and this short code snippet has solved an issue I've been having for a while (despite the solution above which fixed that particular issue). I wish I could mark these both as correct.